# Flipping polygon in libgdx

Tags: java, scala, geometry, libgdx

I have Tiled maps working in libgdx, now I'm trying to do collision with these maps. I figured it'd be really useful just to draw polygons in Tiled and use them for collisions in libgdx. I'd actually prefer it this way rather than doing a per tile collision since it'll give me collision flexibility which the game requires.

I've successfully parsed each object's xml and grabbed the polygon points. I've been able to make a box2d PolygonShape with these and it shows up in game! But it's mirrored upside down...

I figured tiled must be on a different coordinate system than libgdx so I just created a function that finds the max y point and subtracts the rest of the y points from it in correct y flipping fashion. But now I'm getting this error:

```
java: /var/lib/hudson/jobs/libgdx-git/workspace/gdx/jni/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.cpp:115: b2Vec2 ComputeCentroid(const b2Vec2*, int32): Assertion `area > 1.19209289550781250000e-7F' failed.
```

It looks like an error from libgdx's native side. **Is there anyone that can help me figure this out?**

Here's the relevant section from my tmx file.

```
<objectgroup height="20" name="Object Layer 1" width="20">
 <object x="100" y="320">
   <polygon points="0,0 244,1 300,50 300,95 -12,88 -29,19"/>
 </object>
 <object height="104" width="116" x="437" y="175"/>
</objectgroup>
```

Here's the bit of code, it's in Scala, that flips the polygon. It takes a Border object that has a polygon field which is just an array of Vector2s. The _type field is a symbol, it looks like it messes with stackoverflow's syntax highlighting.

```
def flipPolygonY(border: Border){
    if(border._type == 'polygon){
        //find the highest y point
        var max = border.polygon(0).y
        for(vect <- border.polygon){
            max = max.max(vect.y)
        }
        //flip it, take max - y
        for(vect <- border.polygon){
            vect.set(vect.x, max - vect.y)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The assert seems to require that the area of the polygon being added is greater than something like 0.0000001.  box2d may also require the polygon be non-self-intersecting (I can't tell if your is or not though)

Comment: It does work fine without it flipped. This bug is killing me, I'm stuck until I fix it. I could just draw the polygon's upside down to begin with, but that's not really fixing anything and is a shortcut for the bug rather than a fix for it. -- if there is any more information you would like to see let me know.

Comment: Can you try asking box2d for the "area" of the polygon before you flip it and after you flip it?  (Should be the same and larger than 1...)  Perhaps something else is happening to the polygon on its way into box2d?  What call into box2d are you making when you get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured this out, doing some searching I read that Polygons must be defined in clockwise order. So on a hunch I reversed the order of my array or Vector2's. It works. So if anyone else wants to use the polygons from Tiled in libgdx, flip them on the Y-axis and reverse the order.